# Wifi Direct (Wifi P2P) peer data exchange - sensors

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I am trying to emulate this app - Wifi Direct sensors (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=esnetlab.apps.android.wifidirectsensors) 
I have gone through the demo of wifi-direct from android samples. 
I am able to get sensors data on a individual device, but i need to get them from the peers in a wifi-direct group.
So I wanted to know if someone could suggest on how to go about the design/process of getting the sensors data from 'remote sensors' on one device (as shown in the screenshot of that app).

Answer (score 0):

There are basically three components you are going to need...

1. If you're going to want to plot the results, need a plotting library like Androidplot.
2. You're going to need to establish a Wi-Fi direct connection between the devices. There is sample code for this in the android SDK, but it isn't in the newest SDKs, I think it's in levels 14 to 18, or something like that. In the samples, they show you how to open a socket connection and send a file. You just need to leave the socket connections open.
3. The sensor event class is not serializable, and I think its constructor is either protected or private. This makes it difficult to send over a socket since it is difficult to reconstruct the sensor event on the peer. A library like Gson might help with this, but an easier way would be to pick a subclass of information that is important to you and to just send that info.

What you want to do will be a lot of work.